# Too many to's? 'I am not able to come to office'

Tags: word-usage, word-choice

Is this sentence correct or not?

> I am not able to come to office.

Can we use "to" twice or can we write this sentence in a better way?

Comment: It is correct. The first "to" refers to the infinitive "come" and the second is a preposition. But you should give some more context. When are you going to use the sentence?

Comment: What's the problem in using the preposition twice?

Comment: "to" is a mostly invisible word: a listener will notice its absence more than its presence.

Comment: In toto, I am able to come to two offices, too.

Comment: I went to the market to buy a cake to take to the party, but I had to stop to ask Bob to lend me $10.

Comment: two too many to's

Comment: "The office is not somewhere I can come."  There, no "to"s.  ;)

Comment: @Wildcard - nice try but not grammatically correct (unless I misunderstood your meaning)

Answer (score 31, accepted):

I don't think it's incorrect to use the *to come to* form (and [here](https://www.google.it/search?tbm=bks&ei=Yr-pVtqkPMaoUdj7paAD&q="to+come+to"&oq="to+come+to") you may find several examples). However, you should put a determiner (like *the*) before the word *office*:

> I *can't* come to *the* office.

Comment: +1, it's certainly not incorrect to use 'to' multiple times, but it can sound a little better if you vary your words more, so the usage of 'can't' sounds better.

Comment: @DCShannon I'm not sure that's why it's better. *I can't come* sounds more natural than *I'm unable to come* even though there's only one *to* in the latter.

Comment: @DCShannon I disagree that "can't" sounds better. I would just say it sounds more informal. I would probably prefer "am not able" or "am unable" if I were writing something work related, while I would probably prefer "can't" if I were speaking to someone I know well (even my boss, if we were on amicable terms).

Comment: @Araucaria That also. Both of those reasons.

Comment: Using to twice is perfectly fine of course (mostly invisible). But I like "can't come" as it's less formal.

Answer (score 21):

It is fine to use several *to*'s in the same sentence:

- I want to try to learn to ride a bike.

Here we can see three *to*'s in the same sentence. The Original Poster shouldn't change their example. It's a fine sentence.

Comment: Thanks Lord, I've finally understood what *OP* means! :)

Comment: @mrnld Yes, that's why I alwasy write it out in full and use capitals. It took me six months before I understood what it meant!!

Comment: So I'm not the only one to be too lazy to google it! :)

Comment: Overall a good answer, but the OP *should* change their sentence to include the definite article before "office". It should read, "I am not able to come to **the** office." The definite article is used before generic *places* ("**the** store", "**the** racetrack", "**the** restaurant") but is not used before *activities*, as in "I am not able to come **to work**" or "... **to band practice**" or "... **to dinner**".

Comment: @ToddWilcox I agree, I didn't put that it mainly because it isn't the OP's main concern. I was going to edit the article into the original question, but when I read mnlrd's answer, I realised it would have spoiled it so I didn't.

Comment: Not only is the sentence  OK, but so is "I want to try to learn to ride a bike to school."

Comment: @Araucaria Took me a long time too. I just found this in a link on the third result for the search term "jargon" on the SE meta site: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/40353/stack-exchange-glossary-dictionary-of-commonly-used-terms

Answer (score 7):

The two uses of the word "to" are fine but the sentence as a whole sounds weird to me (as a native British English speaker). In my opinion, there should be a "the" in there after the "to":

> I am not able to come to the office.

Comment: British speakers always seem to say "to hospital" opposed to the American speakers "to the hospital." That always sounds weird to me, too, but when I read "to office" I assumed OP is using the same construct as "to hospital"? Two peoples separated by a common language. (Winston Churchill)

Comment: I wonder if we treat words like "hospital", "school" "college" and "university" in this context as activities (like "work") rather than as places (like "office")

Comment: Yes, exactly. Which is why @Ron we _don't_ say that we're going "to office"; that's just weird! But we certainly don't have a monopoly on that construct; I assume that you, too, will at some point tonight be going to bed.

Answer (score 4):

This can be taken as an extended comment on Araucaria's succinct (and entirely correct) answer.

Technically, you're not using the single word 'to' twice; the first instance of 'to' is inexorably wrapped up with the word 'come', as the two words together form the infinitive form of the verb 'to come'. The second instance of 'to' is indicative of direction, placed immediately before a destination (in this case, the office). They have entirely distinct meanings in the sentence.

In other words, these instances of 'to' are [homophonous](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/homophonous), but not [synonymous](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/synonymous). English has many homophones (such as 'mean' or 'bat'), but 'to' is one of the most commonly used, and commonly confused.

Answer (score 3):

The use of "to come" is the [infinitive form](http://www.edufind.com/english-grammar/infinitive/) of "come", in English.

It's also commonly called a [helping verb](https://www.englishclub.com/grammar/verbs-classification-helping.htm).

The second "to" is the [preposition](http://www.chompchomp.com/terms/preposition.htm) of the prepositional phrase, "to office".

As it stands, your sentence does make sense, and would not sound or look strange. That being said, I would recommend adding the article adjective "the" between, "to" and "office".

The resulting sentence would be: "I am not able to come to the office".

Comment: Exactly what I was going to do, break it down into its parts. Excellent.

Comment: And yes, while there's the British/American divide on "hospital", I'm not aware of a dialect that wouldn't use "the" with "office" here.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder really? I wasn't aware some dialects hold that, "I'm going to hospital" is correct. Fascinating!

Comment: Yup, that's the normal way in British English. Also "He's in hospital" not "He's in *the* hospital" as it is in American English. In BrEng, you'd "go to *the* hospital" to visit someone who was there, but you'd "go to hospital" if you were having an operation. So you can tell how concerned to be for them if someone says "I'm going to (the) hospital" depending on whether that "the" is there. :-)

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Wow. I love that; clarity of intent via subtraction. Stupid founding fathers... ;)

Answer (score 2):

the sentence

```
"i am not able to come to office"
```

is correct. because here both "to" have their own meaning first one for infinitives and second one for preposition

and alternative for the same could be

"i am unable to reach the office"

Comment: @Grish, Yes this is good option but our main motive behind this question is to know the usage of multiple to's  in a single sentence.

Answer (score 1):

Although the word "to" is used twice in one sentence, it is used in two different ways.

The first use is as an "infinitive." Specifically, "to come." Many other languages have infinitives, but they often have a suffix to the verb, as opposed to a separate word.

The second use is as a directional preposition, to, in the sense of "toward" or "into.

It's a confusing point in the English language, but you're not really using the same word twice. More like two "similar"-looking words in two different ways.

Answer (score 0):

It's correct.

Here in the US replacing the second *to* with *into* is also acceptable in conversation.

"I am not able to come *into* the office."

or

"I am not able to come in today" If you're speaking to someone you work with, it's implied you're talking about the office.

Answer (score -1):

I think the sentence is correct. But it can be written in a better way:

I will not come to the office.

Comment: "I will not come office" is not correct, you need "to the office".

Comment: @Chenmunka  Thank you for correcting me. I will try to correct my answer as soon as possible.

Comment: I disagree.  The sentence you propose suggests completely different intent.   'Unable to come' Basically means that something is preventing you.  'will not come' comes off as if you just decided you didn't feel like it.